# Understanding the effective potential Energy in the Born-Oppenheimer approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential-energy, born-oppenheimer-approximation

In the Born-Oppenheimer approximation, the effective potential energy, is the potential energy that an electron gains when considering all the inter-particle interactions in a molecule? Said in another way, which particles do experience this effective potential?

Is it correct to say that the effective potential is the intrinsic molecular potential energy?